# IntelliJ: How can I permanently enable line preview on moving caret to ending braces?

Tags: intellij-idea, editor

Moving the caret to the ending braces of a statement (method, class, if/else, etc) will show me a preview of the beginning of the statement on top of the editing window if it is out of screen bounds. Here is a picture for clarity. 
[Screenshot of tooltip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4ea5.png)

What is this feature called and how do I enable it such that the statement preview shows even if my caret is in within the braces and not on the ending brace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`View` | **Context Info** — <kbd>Alt</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> on Mac) + <kbd>Q</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

That tool tip was called "context info" and similar information can displayed by going to settings > Editor > General > Appearance > show breadcrumbs